# Making this JUnit Test pass

Tags: java, junit, server

Here is the test:

```
@Test
public void invalidPort() {
    try {
        SS.main(SS_ARGS);
        assertTrue(false);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Here is the relevant code in SS:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

        if (obj.start() == 0) {
            ...stuff
        }
    } catch (BindException e) {
        System.out.println("Address already in use.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is what obj.start() does:

```
public int start() {
    try {
        HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create(serverURI);
        this.server = server;
        server.start();
        return 0;
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Please specify the server URI");
        return 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Invalid port!");
        return 1;
    }


}
```

In this test I am making sure that the port is invalid. When run, the program prints out "Error: Invalid port!" which is good, but the test doesn't pass. It fails because it reaches the assertTrue(false) line. How can I make this test pass?

Comment: Remove the `assertTrue(false)` line which will *always* fail the test?

Comment: The OP uses this in an idiom to test for expected exceptions.

Comment: But `assertTrue(true)` is a no-op.

Comment: @JimGarrison What do you mean by "no-op"?

Comment: It does nothing.  You are asserting that the constant `true` is `true`, which can never be false under any conditions.

Comment: But I am doing it when the exception is caught, which means that the test always returns true when there is an exception, which is what I want. Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you catch all the relevant exceptions in your main method, the main method will not throw an exception and so your test always fails (because it expects an exception to be thrown).

The console output that you mention comes from the catch block of the exception. If you catch the exception, it is gone and will not be passed to the test.

Generally, it is advisable to construct small, testable methods with input and output values. Testing output for the user (like console output) should usually be avoided. By separating the logic as much as possible from the output, one can test thoroughly without having the problems mentioned above.

Comment: So then how do I make this test pass. Should I not catch the exception in my program? Then when the user runs my program they will get a nasty stack trace error message if they give an invalid port.

Comment: If your start method has return codes, why not test the start method for the correct return codes?

Comment: Because there is a rather complicated set of things that happens when I give an invalid port (file parsing and such). I want to be sure that everything works up to the point where the port is determined to be invalid. I already know the start method will return 1 when the URI it is given (which contains the port) is invalid, that is not what I want to test here.

Comment: Then put the logic you want to test into a separate method. You cannot and should not test for console output. Rather define some method like isPortInvalid and test this method. And if you downvoted me, please check again if my answer is so wrong.

Comment: Your answer provided a correct explanation of why my test failed but check again if that was what I was asking.

Comment: This comment here answers my question though, so thank you. I would upvote you but it says my vote is locked until you edit. Perhaps edit with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Test(expected=IllegalStateException.class)
public void invalidPort() {
        SS.main(SS_ARGS);
}
```

Replace IllegalStateException with the actual exception implementation that you're expecting. (Perhaps you should be throwing an exception from your main method, rather than just logging it to stderr?)

Comment: I don't want to throw an exception from my main method though. I want to catch the exception and print an informative and nice error message. How do I test for this in the JUnit test?

Comment: In that case, you should probably move your logging logic to a separate method/class. Then you can use a mock framework (like EasyMock, JMock, or Mockito) to validate that the logger was invoked correctly.